# MAMP PRO 4+ after update osx to macOS Sierra disappears hosts /etc/hosts

Tags: macos, mamp, mamp-pro, virtual-hosts, macos-sierra

after update osx to macOS Sierra my MAMP PRO sometimes not working correctly.
When i start servers, MAMP write my hosts to /etc/hosts, but after some time (seconds), my hosts desappears from /etc/hosts.
After several server restarts hosts stay.

Has anyone with this problem experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with version 4.1 (approx.) was this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem where my hosts disappeared from /etc/hosts after I put my OS in sleepmode (macOS Sierra).

I noticed I was also running a VPN (Pulse Secure) and after disabling the VPN the hosts stopped disappearing. Maybe you're also running a VPN which removes the hosts?

Answer (score -1):

Since Mac OS X Sierra now features placing Desktop and Documents in iCloud,  could it be that MAMP PRO Root Directory is in Documents folder in iCloud and MAMP PRO is expecting root folder to be local on machine?